# How to adjust column widths of JQuery datatable in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I use the following tag to include a JQuery DataTable in my Rails app:

```
<%= content_tag :table,
                role: :dts_datatable,
                id: 'dts',
                style: 'height:500px; overflow-y: auto;',
                class: 'table table-responsive  reconciletable  table-striped table-bordered table-hover',
                data: { url: dts_path(format: :json)} do %>
```

I would like to specify widths of the individual columns of this datatable and am not sure if and how I could do it in the above `content_tag`.

Please help!

Comment: You shouldn't have css in your views, that goes against conventions. A table is just rows (tr) with columns (td) so you just have to specify a width to the `td` child that you want. For example, for each tr, you could set a 70% width to `td:nth-child(2)`

Comment: @escanxr - Thanks much for the reply! Using the `content_tag` shown in my original question, how can I modify the column widths? Pls help!